# How long will classmap.php be supported

Tags: joomla-4.x

We are migrating to Joomla 4 and have a lot of code dependent on the 'J' classes that are presently aliased by classmap.php; I see that it is still present in Joomla 5

Will this aliasing continue to be supported through future releases or will it be phased out?